# Where does Realtek Audio Control (one installed from Microsoft Store) store its settings?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, backup, realtek-hd-audio

I am trying to find where does the **Realtek Audio Control**, installed from [*Microsoft Store*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/realtek-audio-control/9p2b8mcsvpln), store its settings, as at each motherboard's audio drivers update I get it reset!!

Location of the Realtek Audio Control installation files is this:

> C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Packages\RealtekSemiconductorCorp.RealtekAudioControl_dt26b99r8h8gj

But there are no active setting files that do get modified and so stores new edited settings to the app.

I am searching for files and folder in `C:`, but I'm suspecting that might be a regedit entry.

Any help?

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you checked the AppData folder, accessed by typing 'appdata' into the Run dialog box (Win + R)? It may have a folder there.

Comment: No, no Realtek folder anywhere. Can't really find where does this Microsoft Store app store its settings. Is there a place where generally they are stored? I thought that it was their installation folders, like the one linked up here, and I have searched the Regedit, but with no success. Any help?

Comment: Anyone knows nothing about this? I am still searching... Thank you.